# Can't add external rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-string

I've got the following code in my functions.php

```
function add_custom_rewrite_rules(){

   add_rewrite_tag('%gallery%','([^/]+)', 'gallery=');
   add_rewrite_tag('%album%','([^/]+)', 'album=');

   add_rewrite_rule('galleries/(.+)/?$' , 'index.php?pagename=galleries&album=1&gallery=$matches[1]');
}

add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

But the rewrite rule is not getting added, and it doesn't show up in my list of rewrites in the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't ever do this:

```
add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
```

Every time WordPress loads, you are going to flush the rewrite rules. You only need to do this once to make sure your rewrite shows up.

Second, `add_rewrite_tag` only takes two arguments, the tag and the regex. If you want to specify a query variable directly, you'll need to do something like this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->add_rewrite_tag('%gallery%','([^/]+)', 'gallery=');
$wp_query->add_rewrite_tag('%album%','([^/]+)', 'album=');
```

In your case, it doesn't really matter: you're using the same query variable as the tag.

Finally, there were some errors in your regex.  You need to start with a carrot, and I wouldn't use `(.*)` for second part.  You also need to specify the third argument of `add_rewrite_rule` which tells WP where to place the rewrite in prominence.  You want `top` to tell WordPress that this rule should come *before* the built in rules.

This works:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse41778_add_rewrite' );
function wpse41778_add_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%gallery%','([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%album%','([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^galleries/([^/]+)/?$', 
        'index.php?pagename=galleries&album=1&gallery=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Provided you flush the rewrite rules.  If you drop the rules into a plugin you can use `register_activation_hook` to flush them.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse41778_flush_rewrite' );
function wpse41778_flush_rewrite()
{
    wpse41778_add_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

To get the value of the `gallery` or `album` query variables you can do this:

```
$gallery = get_query_var( 'gallery' );
$album = get_query_var( 'album' );
```

Based on your rewrite, your usage is probably going to be something like this:

```
<?php
if( get_query_var( 'album' ) )
{
    $gallery = get_query_var( 'gallery' );
    // do stuff with $gallery
}
```

Here is the rewrite part of that as [a plugin](https://gist.github.com/1781733).

Comment: thank you very much, i knew i had the regex wrong but i couldn't figure out the correct one